# Get full raw http request (complete with headers and body)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, webob

In a appengine project im trying to get the whole http request inside an webapp2.RequestHandler:

```
class ConnectedHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):        
    logging.info("Someone connected: " + self.request.get('from'))
    # How to get the raw http request from self.request?
```

Having looked through the documentation im begining to think its not possible

The result im looking for is something like this (What i would call a http request anyways):

```
POST /6473924464345088 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:10083
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.3.0

{
    "u": "a"
}
```

**Edit**: Updated the example

Is there another cleaver way to access this data when using webapp2 ?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you exactly that:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.write('Just received:\n\n' + str(self.request))
```